# I cant access html files from my document root

Tags: html, apache, apache2

I have index.html in /var/www, which is my root document directory. I also have relevantskills.html in the same directory. The first link on index.html leads me to relevantskills.html. When I go to my website at http://brianhotopp.cf/ I can see index.html, and when I click on the first link, it displays relevantskills.html. However, when I try to access relevantskills.html from http://brianhotopp.cf/relevantskills.html, It brings me to index.html. Also I cannot view images in my root document directory. For example, I have a png called favicon, but when I go to mywebsite/favicon.png, it displays the default favicon for my domain name provider, not the one I have in /var/www. Is this a problem with my configuration? My permissions? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website is running inside an iframe, that's why it is not working. When you're clicking on a link, your browser is not "redirected" but the website in the iframe is. That's also why you don't see any changes in the url bar on top of your browser.

I suppose you don't want to see your website inside an iframe. If this is the case, you better contact your hosting company because this is a dirty way of hosting websites.

Comment: It is a free domain name so I dont think I'm going to get much help from freenom. Do you have any recommendations for domain name providers that dont force my website into an iframe? I am hosting my files on a raspberry pi.

Comment: I have some good alternatives when you're living in Belgium which probably isn't the case. Google might be able to help you. Good luck searching!

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm now using duckdns for my website and all is well :P